# Error Updating Excel .xlsx file with Java POI on Android

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

Hello I am trying to update an existing Excel file In my app while using Java.

The file is located in the internal storage of the device and I'm wondering if I need to change the excel file type in order to have this working correctly. I changed from an HSSFWorkbook to an XSSFWorkbook because the HSSFWorkbook said there was an issue with the file header.

This is my code:

```
        exStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

        Log.e("DIRECTORY", exStorageDirectory);


       try {


           InputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(exStorageDirectory + "/ZCK Orders/ZLM_Order_MASTER.xlsx"));

           XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

           XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);


           dateRow = sheet.getRow(4);

           dateCell = dateRow.getCell(7);

           dateCell.setCellValue(currentDate);

           //Quesitos

           quesitoRow = sheet.getRow(8);

           quesitoCell = quesitoRow.getCell(7);

           quesitoCell.setCellValue(quesitoOrder);

           //Guava


           guavaRow = sheet.getRow(9);

           guavaCell = guavaRow.getCell(7);

           guavaCell.setCellValue(guavaOrder);

           //Guava Cheese

           guavaCheeseRow = sheet.getRow(10);

           guavaCheeseCell = guavaCheeseRow.getCell(7);

           guavaCheeseCell.setCellValue(guavaCheeseOrder);

           //Cuban Bread

           cubanBreadRow = sheet.getRow(11);

           cubanBreadCell = cubanBreadRow.getCell(7);

           cubanBreadCell.setCellValue(cubanBreadOrder);

           //Media Noche

           mediaNocheRow = sheet.getRow(12);

           mediaNocheCell = mediaNocheRow.getCell(7);

           mediaNocheCell.setCellValue(mediaNocheOrder);

           //Fries

           friesRow = sheet.getRow(13);

           friesCell = friesRow.getCell(7);

           friesCell.setCellValue(friesOrder);

           //Tostones

           tostonesRow = sheet.getRow(14);

           tostonesCell = tostonesRow.getCell(7);

           tostonesCell.setCellValue(tostonesOrder);

           //Maduros

           madurosRow = sheet.getRow(15);

           madurosCell = madurosRow.getCell(7);

           madurosCell.setCellValue(madurosOrder);

           //Palomilla

           palomillaRow = sheet.getRow(16);

           palomillaCell = palomillaRow.getCell(7);

           palomillaCell.setCellValue(palomillaOrder);

           //Croq

           croquetasRow = sheet.getRow(17);

           croquetasCell = croquetasRow.getCell(7);

           croquetasCell.setCellValue(croquetasOrder);

           //Chicken Soup

           chickenSoupRow = sheet.getRow(18);

           chickenSoupCell = chickenSoupRow.getCell(7);

           chickenSoupCell.setCellValue(chickenSoupOrder);

           //Veggie Meat

           veggieMeatRow = sheet.getRow(19);

           veggieMeatCell = veggieMeatRow.getCell(7);

           veggieMeatCell.setCellValue(veggieMeatOrder);

           //Turkey Patty

           turkeyRow = sheet.getRow(20);

           turkeyCell = turkeyRow.getCell(7);

           turkeyCell.setCellValue(turkeyOrder);

           //Bacon

           baconRow = sheet.getRow(21);

           baconCell = baconRow.getCell(7);

           baconCell.setCellValue(baconOrder);

           //Mahi Mahi

           mahiRow = sheet.getRow(22);

           mahiCell = mahiRow.getCell(7);

           mahiCell.setCellValue(mahiOrder);

           //Beef Emp

           beefEmpRow = sheet.getRow(23);

           beefEmpCell = beefEmpRow.getCell(7);

           beefEmpCell.setCellValue(beefEmpOrder);

           //Chicken Emp

           chickenEmpRow = sheet.getRow(24);

           chickenEmpCell = chickenEmpRow.getCell(7);

           chickenEmpCell.setCellValue(chickenEmpOrder);

           //Ham Cheese

           hcEmpRow = sheet.getRow(25);

           hcEmpCell = hcEmpRow.getCell(7);

           hcEmpCell.setCellValue(hcEmpOrder);

           //Mini Beef Emp

           miniBeefEmpRow = sheet.getRow(26);

           miniBeefEmpCell = miniBeefEmpRow.getCell(7);

           miniBeefEmpCell.setCellValue(miniBeefEmpOrder);

           //Mini Chicken Emp

           miniChickenEmpRow = sheet.getRow(27);

           miniChickenEmpCell = miniChickenEmpRow.getCell(7);

           miniChickenEmpCell.setCellValue(miniChickenEmpOrder);

           //Prov

           provRow = sheet.getRow(28);

           provCell = provRow.getCell(7);

           provCell.setCellValue(provOrder);

           //Swiss

           swissRow = sheet.getRow(29);

           swissCell = swissRow.getCell(7);

           swissCell.setCellValue(swissOrder);

           //Cilantro

           cilantroRow = sheet.getRow(30);

           cilantroCell = cilantroRow.getCell(7);

           cilantroCell.setCellValue(cilantroOrder);

           //Pickles

           picklesRow = sheet.getRow(31);

           picklesCell = picklesRow.getCell(7);

           picklesCell.setCellValue(picklesOrder);

           //Chop Onions

           chopOnionsRow = sheet.getRow(32);

           chopOnionsCell = chopOnionsRow.getCell(7);

           chopOnionsCell.setCellValue(chopOnionsOrder);

           //Eggs

           eggsRow = sheet.getRow(33);

           eggsCell = eggsRow.getCell(7);

           eggsCell.setCellValue(eggsOrder);

           //Butter

           butterRow = sheet.getRow(34);

           butterCell = butterRow.getCell(7);

           butterCell.setCellValue(butterOrder);

           //Lettuce

           lettuceRow = sheet.getRow(35);

           lettuceCell = lettuceRow.getCell(7);

           lettuceCell.setCellValue(lettuceOrder);

           //Pork

           porkRow = sheet.getRow(36);

           porkCell = porkRow.getCell(7);

           porkCell.setCellValue(porkOrder);

           //Chicken

           chickenRow = sheet.getRow(37);

           chickenCell = chickenRow.getCell(7);

           chickenCell.setCellValue(chickenOrder);

           //Vaca

           vacaRow = sheet.getRow(38);

           vacaCell = vacaRow.getCell(7);

           vacaCell.setCellValue(vacaOrder);

           //Congri

           congriRow = sheet.getRow(39);

           congriCell = congriRow.getCell(7);

           congriCell.setCellValue(congriOrder);

           //Black B

           blackBeansRow = sheet.getRow(40);

           blackBeansCell = blackBeansRow.getCell(7);

           blackBeansCell.setCellValue(blackBeansOrder);

           //Red B

           redBeansRow = sheet.getRow(41);

           redBeansCell = redBeansRow.getCell(7);

           redBeansCell.setCellValue(redBeansOrder);

           //Ropa Vieja

           ropaRow = sheet.getRow(42);

           ropaCell = ropaRow.getCell(7);

           ropaCell.setCellValue(ropaOrder);

           //Red Peppers

           peppersRow = sheet.getRow(43);

           peppersCell = peppersRow.getCell(7);

           peppersCell.setCellValue(peppersOrder);

           //Garlic

           garlicRow = sheet.getRow(44);

           garlicCell = garlicRow.getCell(7);

           garlicCell.setCellValue(garlicOrder);

           //B Ham

           breakHamRow = sheet.getRow(45);

           breakHamCell = breakHamRow.getCell(7);

           breakHamCell.setCellValue(breakHamOrder);

           //Cuban Ham

           cubHamRow = sheet.getRow(46);

           cubHamCell = cubHamRow.getCell(7);

           cubHamCell.setCellValue(cubHamOrder);

           //Picadillo

           picadilloRow = sheet.getRow(47);

           picadilloCell = picadilloRow.getCell(7);

           picadilloCell.setCellValue(picadilloOrder);;

           //Mojo

           mojitoRow = sheet.getRow(48);

           mojitoCell = mojitoRow.getCell(7);

           mojitoCell.setCellValue(mojitoOrder);

           //Veggies

           veggiesRow = sheet.getRow(49);

           veggiesCell = veggiesRow.getCell(7);

           veggiesCell.setCellValue(veggiesOrder);

           //Potatoes

           potatoesRow = sheet.getRow(50);

           potatoesCell = potatoesRow.getCell(7);

           potatoesCell.setCellValue(potatoesOrder);

           //Onions

           roastOnionsRow = sheet.getRow(51);

           roastOnionsCell = roastOnionsRow.getCell(7);

           roastOnionsCell.setCellValue(roastOnionsOrder);

           //Flan

           flanRow = sheet.getRow(52);

           flanCell = flanRow.getCell(7);

           flanCell.setCellValue(flanOrder);

           //Cubaioli

           cubaioliRow = sheet.getRow(53);

           cubaioliCell = cubaioliRow.getCell(7);

           cubaioliCell.setCellValue(cubaioliOrder);

           //Mayoketchup

           mayoKRow = sheet.getRow(54);

           mayoKCell = mayoKRow.getCell(7);

           mayoKCell.setCellValue(mayoKOrder);

           //Zaza Verde

           hotSauceRow = sheet.getRow(55);

           hotSauceCell = hotSauceRow.getCell(7);

           hotSauceCell.setCellValue(hotSauceOrder);

           //OJ

           ojRow = sheet.getRow(56);

           ojCell = ojRow.getCell(7);

           ojCell.setCellValue(ojOrder);

           //Milk

           milkRow = sheet.getRow(57);

           milkCell = milkRow.getCell(7);

           milkCell.setCellValue(milkOrder);

           //Fat Free

           fatFreeRow = sheet.getRow(58);

           fatFreeCell = fatFreeRow.getCell(7);

           fatFreeCell.setCellValue(fatFreeOrder);

           //Almond

           almondRow = sheet.getRow(59);

           almondCell = almondRow.getCell(7);

           almondCell.setCellValue(almondOrder);

           //Adobo

           adoboRow = sheet.getRow(60);

           adoboCell = adoboRow.getCell(7);

           adoboCell.setCellValue(adoboOrder);

           //Almibar

           almibarRow = sheet.getRow(61);

           almibarCell = almibarRow.getCell(7);

           almibarCell.setCellValue(almibarOrder);

           //Jupina

           jupinaRow = sheet.getRow(62);

           jupinaCell = jupinaRow.getCell(7);

           jupinaCell.setCellValue(jupinaOrder);

           //Cola

           colaRow = sheet.getRow(63);

           colaCell = colaRow.getCell(7);

           colaCell.setCellValue(colaOrder);

           //Malta

           maltaRow = sheet.getRow(64);

           maltaCell = maltaRow.getCell(7);

           maltaCell.setCellValue(maltaOrder);

           file.close();

           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                   exStorageDirectory + "/ZCKOrders/ZLM_ZCK_Order_"
                           + tomorrow +".xls"));
           workbook.write(fos);

           fos.close();


       } catch (FileNotFoundException e){

           Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       } catch (IOException e ){

           Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       } 
    }
```

This is the error I get in my Log:

```
2020-07-16 02:16:12.646 22351-22351/com.customapps.zazatrainingapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.customapps.zazatrainingapp, PID: 22351
    java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #238 bootstrap method
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection.<init>(PackagePartCollection.java:47)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:241)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:732)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:310)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:47)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:309)
        at com.example.jorge.zazaii.ZNCD.Management.ZLM.Orders.ZCKOrderFinal.updateExcelFile(ZCKOrderFinal.java:649)
        at com.example.jorge.zazaii.ZNCD.Management.ZLM.Orders.ZCKOrderFinal.access$100(ZCKOrderFinal.java:40)
        at com.example.jorge.zazaii.ZNCD.Management.ZLM.Orders.ZCKOrderFinal$1.onClick(ZCKOrderFinal.java:255)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6610)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6583)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26076)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6702)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Bootstrap method returned null
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection.<init>(PackagePartCollection.java:47) 
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:241) 
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:732) 
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:310) 
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:47) 
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:309) 
        at com.example.jorge.zazaii.ZNCD.Management.ZLM.Orders.ZCKOrderFinal.updateExcelFile(ZCKOrderFinal.java:649) 
        at com.example.jorge.zazaii.ZNCD.Management.ZLM.Orders.ZCKOrderFinal.access$100(ZCKOrderFinal.java:40) 
        at com.example.jorge.zazaii.ZNCD.Management.ZLM.Orders.ZCKOrderFinal$1.onClick(ZCKOrderFinal.java:255) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6610) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6583) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:780) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26076) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6702) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
```

I have been searching BootstrapMethodError but apparently there many different types. I know that it has found the file because perviously the log gave me the error of not finding the file.
If anyone can guide me I'd truly appreciate it, Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54224065/bootstrap-method-returned-null-android-crash-immediately-on-launch ?

Comment: BTW Apache POI is for Java - it does not support Android -- because Android omits certain key Java packages. Some people have tried with varying levels of success to get POI to work on Android.

Comment: I have used it to create Excel files, do you know any other methods of updating an excel file with Android?

Comment: HSSFWorkbook is for the legacy .xls file format and is more likely to work than XSSFWorkbook (which is for the current .xlsx format). These file formats are very different. XSSFWorkbook depends on the Java Runtime for XML parsing features and Android omits many of these features.

Comment: I used HSSF at first and it was giving me an error about the header of my template. Now it gives me this bootstrap error... I think i will go back to creating the file from scratch.